# Store dispatch recalls the http get of the effect several times

Tags: rxjs, angular7, store

During dispatch, my effect is called repeatedly until my backend responds and the data is loaded. I need help in understanding how to load the data with just one GET REQUEST and then load from the store if the data is actually already present.

```
      this.cases$ = this.store
          .pipe(
            takeWhileAlive(this),
            select(selectImportTaskCasesData),
            tap(
              (cases) => {
                if (cases.length <= 0) {
                  this.store.dispatch(new ImportTaskLoadCasesAction());
                }
              }),
            filter((cases) => {
              return cases.length > 0;
            }),
            tap(() => {
              this.store.dispatch(new ImportTaskLoadCasesLoadedFromStoreAction());
            }),
            shareReplay()
          );

export const selectCasesData = createSelector(
  selectImportTaskCasesState,
  state => state ? state.cases : []
);

export const selectImportTaskCasesData = createSelector(
  selectCasesData,
  cases => {
    return cases.slice(0);
  }
);


 @Effect()
  ImportCasesLoad$: Observable<any> = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType<ImportTaskLoadCasesAction>(ImportCasesActionTypes.ImportTaskLoadCasesAction),
      map((action: ImportTaskLoadCasesAction) => action),
      switchMap((payload) => {
        return this.importCases.get()
          .pipe(
            map(response => {
              return new ImportTaskLoadCasesSuccessAction({ total: response['count'], cases: response['results'] });
            }),
            catchError((error) => {
              this.logger.error(error);
              return of(new ImportTaskLoadCasesLoadErrorAction(error));
            })
          );
      })
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the below work? This is assuming you have a reducer that handles the `ImportTaskLoadCasesSuccessAction`; Maybe supplying a working example will help, as there is a bit of guessing as how state is being managed.

```
   this.cases$ = this.store
      .pipe(
        takeWhileAlive(this),
        select(selectImportTaskCasesData),
        tap(
          (cases) => {
            if (cases.length <= 0) {
              this.store.dispatch(new ImportTaskLoadCasesAction());
            }
          }),
        // personally, I would have the component/obj that is consuming this.cases$ null check the cases$, removed for brevity
        shareReplay()
      );

  export const selectCasesData = createSelector(
    selectImportTaskCasesState,
    state => state ? state.cases : []
  );

  export const selectImportTaskCasesData = createSelector(
    selectCasesData,
    cases => {
      return cases.slice(0);
    }
  );


 @Effect()
  ImportCasesLoad$: Observable<any> = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType<ImportTaskLoadCasesAction>(ImportCasesActionTypes.ImportTaskLoadCasesAction),
      mergeMap(() => this.importCases.get()
          .pipe(
            map(response => {
              return new ImportTaskLoadCasesSuccessAction({
                total: response['count'],
                cases: response['results']
              });
            }),
            // catch error code removed for brevity
          );
      )
    );
```

If you only want the call `this.importCases.get()` to fire one time, I suggest moving the action dispatch out of the `.pipe(tap(...))`. As this will fire every time a subscription happens.

Instead, set up this.cases$ to always return the result of `select(selectImportTaskCasesData),`. Functionally, you probably want it to always return an array. But that is up to your designed desire.
Foe example ...

```
this.cases$ = this.store
  .pipe(
    takeWhileAlive(this),
    select(selectImportTaskCasesData),
  );
```

Separately, like in a constructor, you can dispatch the `this.store.dispatch(new ImportTaskLoadCasesAction());`. If you want it to only get called when cases$ is empty, you can always wrap it in a method.

e.g.

```
export class exampleService() {
  ensureCases(): void {
    this.store.pipe(
      select(selectImportTaskCasesData), 
      take(1)
    ).subscribe(_cases => {
      if (_cases && _cases.length < 1 ) {
        this.store.dispatch(new ImportTaskLoadCasesAction());
      }
    }),
  }
}
```

Comment: See my answer below yours, i post an example with my reducer's case

Comment: does the reducer case get called more than once?
How many things are subscribing to `this.cases$`? Every subscription will run through the `tap` functions which will fire the action (`ImportTaskLoadCasesAction`) repeadedly, which will fire  `this.importCases.get()` repeadedly.

Comment: I need this.cases$ for populating my kendo-dropdown like this : [data]="cases$ | async" so if i subscribe i can't assign this method : this.cases$ = this.ensureCases() , I need the return value for my dropdown.

Comment: I am not suggesting you remove the assignment of `cases$`. I am suggesting that the call to load data from the api may not need to be part of the `cases$` assignment.

Comment: Ok, so i have to call this method , but subsequently how can i assign my result on my Observable variable cases$ ?

Comment: ok i'll try to do first this.cases$ = this.store...etc and subsequently call the method with dispatch, automatically the results will be found in my Observable cause we have a takeWhileAlive and selector. right?

Comment: It sounds like  a yes. Hard to say without actually seeing the component's code.

Comment: ok tomorrow i'll try your solution and I'll let you know. for now, thanks

Comment: Doesen't work, append in loading status.. if i remove take(1) it's works but i've got a several http request.. i don't know i can't resolve.

Comment: Probably the problem is that, i have 2 component in my page, one use a store effect and the second another store effect. The success of the second subscribe my store property, there is a way to syncronize my store effects ?

Comment: here is a working stackblitz of the ngrx/effects example. I have made 2 components that read from the same selector. Maybe this will help. https://angular-ngrx-store-effects.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have a reducer for handeling my Success Action like this :

```
    case ImportCasesActionTypes.ImportTaskLoadCasesSuccessAction:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    cases: action.payload.cases,
    total: action.payload.total
  };
```

It's called in my effects.

Comment: I updated my previous answer with more details. I am still guessing at what is causing this part of your question. "During dispatch, my effect is called repeatedly until my backend responds and the data is loaded."